# How to update a BigQuery Table from Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a database in Firebase RTDB and built a function that outputs a JSONL file inside a Google Cloud Storage bucket.

I then built a table from Bigquery that connects to that file called data_export.json. The problem I'm having is that when the data_export.json is updated, the BigQuery table is not automatically updated.

Is there a way to directly link the BigQuery to data_export.json in such a way that when the file is updated, the table is automatically updated? What would the step by step look like?

I was reading this link https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/external-data-sources, but couldn't see how I could make a practical application towards google storage.

I also tried to do a cloud function but couldn't get the table connection properly.

What would be the best approach to ensure that every time a file is updated in the GDS, the Bigquery table is also updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options here:

1. Create an external data source. This means that you have a table in Bigquery pointing to a CS file, the data are not stored in BigQuery so you will have a lower performance.

Here you can see the limitations and how to do it for a JSONL file. All the steps are done in BigQuery so if you access Cloud Storage you will not see any option to load it to BigQuery: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-json

2. Use a Cloud Function. You can create a Cloud Function that executes every time a new file is added to a Cloud Storage bucket. You will have to use the BQ library to insert the data in BQ.

Cloud Function Trigger: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage
BQ library: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries

The faster and simpler way is option 1. But the final decision should be made taking into account the use that you are going to do of this table. If you are going to do queries that will really benefit BQ performance  I will go with option 2.

Let me know if you need further information or have any additional doubts.